# Display data of NSMutable String in table View

Tags: iphone

i am accessing web services, which give me result in string array.
Say if the length of string array is 3,
 The first string is "1|123|Bank Of America|111|recall" (| is a delimiter)
The second String is "2|456|JP Morgan|22|recall"
The Third String is "3|1789|Amex|333|recall"

Now when i parse the  SOAP web services, the result is in a NSMutable String.
For the First string value , The Value of Mutable String is "1|123|Bank Of America|111|recall"
Second time when the parser encounters the return tag, the value of MutableString is
"1|123|Bank Of America|111|recall2|456|JP Morgan|22|recall"
And Third Time it becomes "1|123|Bank Of America|111|recall2|456|JP Morgan|22|recall3|1789|Amex|333|recall"

I want to display the 3 strings , by removing the delimiter ("|") in a table View, how am i to do it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want just to change "|" symbol to another then you can use NSMutableString's method:

```
- (NSUInteger)replaceOccurrencesOfString:(NSString *)target withString:(NSString *)replacement options:(NSStringCompareOptions)opts range:(NSRange)searchRange
```

You can also obtain an array of the parts of your string separated with "|" using either NSString's `-componentsSeparatedByString` or `-componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet` methods

Answer (score 0):

Use `[yourMutableString componentsSeparatedByString: @"|recall"]` to obtain an array of your three strings if you store them all concatenated. Then, take each component and split it by the @"|" string: `[eachComponent componentsSeparatedByString: @"|"]`, and display the resulting substrings in UILabels addes as children of each UITableViewCell's contentView.

[Here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e0zi5pQgpaY)'s a video tutorial on working with UITableView.

Comment: thanks, but i am new to iphone application development. how do i add the UIlabel as a child of table view